# How to bind a function without particular event to dynamically added elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So for example I have a function that finds all elements with `"my-box"` class and adds element with `"another-box"` class right after it on `.ready()` and it all works fine. The question is, how do I activate this function on dynamically added `"my-box"` elements? I know that I could use `.on()` if I had a click event or whatnot, but I dont bind any default events so I don't know how to use `.on()` in this case ...

Comment: you can try `on('ready',...)`

Comment: I am not sure if .ready() triggers once some element has been dynamically added but I will try it, thanks

Comment: Ready() only triggers once, when Document is ready.

Comment: When you create this element, just use some callback function. Only need to apply `another-box` for this element, since every other element already has it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 ways:

1. You bind a callback to the event that triggers box insertion. (like a click in a "addBox" button or something)
2. You watch for DOM changes in the parent of the boxes

I would go with 1, however, since watching for DOM changes is expensive

---

## Examples

### Example 1:

Add two boxes simultaneously in the same callback

```js
//event that creates My-Boxes
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
    // In here we add the 2 boxes simultaneously
    $('<div class="my-box">My Box</div>')
    .append('<div class="another-box">Another box</div>')
    .appendTo('#parent');
});
```

```css
.my-box {
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.another-box {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
</div>
<br>
<button id="btn">Add My-Box</button>
<br>
```

### Example 2:

Use DOM Watcher...

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
    $('<div class="my-box">My Box</div>').appendTo('#parent');
});

var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;
var obsConfig = { childList: true, characterData: false, attributes: false, subtree: true};
var parentObserver = new MutationObserver( function (mRecords) {
    
    mRecords.forEach ( function (mutation) {
        if (mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
            for (var i=0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; ++i) {
                if ($(mutation.addedNodes[i]).hasClass('my-box')) {
                    $(mutation.addedNodes[i]).append('<div class="another-box">Another Box</div>');
                }
            }
        }
    });
});

parentObserver.observe($('#parent')[0], obsConfig);
```

```css
.my-box {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.another-box {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent"></div>
<button id="btn">Add Box</button>
```

Comment: @RayonDabre [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: Could you describe a little more the first method you mentioned, please? I am not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: @RayonDabre, you mean that if the new elements are added with Ajax for example, I should trigger the insertion function manually in the ajax success callback?

Comment: @JustMichael Or just attach a new success handler to the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you will want to bind to the document's ready event. This will wait till the document is loaded and it will allow your code to run after the document has been fully returned from the server.

The easiest way to do this (and not use a library like jQuery) to use a self executing anonymous function:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Your HTML here

<script>
(function() {
   // the document will be loaded here

})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It IS binded to the .ready() event but it doesnt work if the element wasnt there when the event triggered because it will be added later dynamically, after the .ready() has been triggered

Comment: Then you will need to bind on the ready event for the dynamically load elements.

Comment: how do I do that? .on('ready', ...) doesn't seem to work for dynamically added ones

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Judging from the comments I would think yes. This can very depending on how the elements are being generated. It might be easiest to use a deferred promise if this is something dynamically loaded from a remote source.
If this is from a straight ajax call there is the [ajax complete method](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/).

Comment: I guess I will manually trigger the function again in the .ajaxComplete callback, I just thought there was some way to avoid it and make it trigger automatically so I wouldn't have to be afraid of forgetting adding the function in every relevant ajaxComplete callback

Comment: Without seeing the code I don't think I could be of any more help. Normally if we are waiting for ajax to complete we would use the [complete](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) callback before trying to use the ajaxcomplete method. The ajaxComplete method is used more when you are waiting for another script to finish its thing.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5avtsqnz/2/)

You can come up with two approaches,

1. Bind every new element with the event, here you need to keep in mind that you need to attach the event to the newly added element only, e.g if you add the event to all the classes, then the event will get attached to all the previous elements twice.
2. Bind the event with the body so that it will automatically keep a record of all the events with which the event has to be triggered.

So best way is to

```
$('body').on('click', '.deleteButton > a', function () {
    alert('attached');
    $(this).parent().append("<br><a href='#'>✖</a>");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: as I mentioned in the question, I'd do that if I had a click event or any other default jquery event